# find all end subdirectories in a tree

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface, find, directory

given the following structure:

```
oz123@debian:~/ $ tree .
.
├── a
│   ├── a1
│   ├── a2
│   └── a3
├── a1
│   ├── a11
│   ├── a12
│   └── a31
├── b
│   └── b1
│       ├── b11
│       │   └── b21
│       │       └── b31
│       ├── b12
│       └── b3
└── c

16 directories, 0 files
```

#### How do I find all the end nodes?

I found the following solutions which *seems* to be good, but I have to proof that there is not test case which will fail it.

The help page of the `-links` states:

> You can also search for files that have a certain number of links,
>   with ‘-links’. Directories normally have at least two hard links;
>   their . entry is the second one. If they have subdirectories, each of
>   those also has a hard link called .. to its parent directory. The .
>   and .. directory entries are not normally searched unless they are
>   mentioned on the find command line.

#### possible solution:

```
oz123@debian:~/ $ find .  -type d  -links 2
./a/a2
./a/a3
./a/a1
./c
./a1/a31
./a1/a11
./a1/a12
./b/b1/b12
./b/b1/b3
./b/b1/b11/b21/b31
```

- Can anyone provide a better solution (without using pipes and sed, this has be performant ...)
- Will it work on any filesystem?

Comment: It will work on any UNIX filesystem, don't know how the `vfat` and `ntfs-3g` drivers emulate inode semantics.

Comment: @HubertKario, a most important question will it work on NetApp filers over NFS?

Comment: I'm not sure about NetApp, but it works over NFS between Linux boxes so I'd guess that yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269798/use-gnu-find-to-show-only-the-leaf-directories

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '(ls -p "{}"|grep />/dev/null)||echo "{}"' \;
```

Slower than

```
find .  -type d  -links 2
```

anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one-liner:

```
find . -type d -execdir sh -c 'test -z "$(find "{}" -mindepth 1 -type d)" && echo $PWD/{}' ';'
```